# Compiz closed in error w/ Unity plugin off, system disabled

Tags: compiz

I was trying to do the 3d cube, but I toggled the Ubuntu unity plugin off, so my Ubuntu Wouldn't crash. then I ACCEDENTALLY closed compiz. I can't do anyhthing. HELP?

Answer (score 1):

Login into virtual console (ctrl+alt+F1) and run the below commands to reset ccsm and unity,

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Back to gui mode,

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (ctrl+alt+t), then type :

```
unity --reset
```

If you can't acces the terminal use the virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)